# Shadow on UILabel does not appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, quartz-graphics

I want to add a little shadow to my UILabel, but it is not showing up.

```
companyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        companyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        companyLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        companyLabel.minimumFontSize = 10.0; 
        companyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        companyLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:103.0/255.0 green:103.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        companyLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:241.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
        companyLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
        companyLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're not setting `shadowOpacity`, which defaults to `0.0`. You need to set that to something else to make the shadow show up. However, there's no reason to even touch `CALayer` right now because `UILabel` has its own `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` properties.

```
companyLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:241.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
companyLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to further customize the shadow? I'm missing properties like radius or spread (as in programs like photoshop).

Comment: @bijan: Not on `UILabel` itself. If you want to add a shadow to the `CALayer`, that supports more properties (such as `shadowRadius`). However, putting a shadow on the layer is going to be less performant than putting it on the label.

Comment: *“there's no reason to even touch CALayer right now because UILabel has its own shadowColor and shadowOffset properties.”* eh? This shadow applies to the text, not the view. These are different things.

Comment: @MaxHowell: The CALayer shadow properties apply to the content in the layer, not the bounds of the layer. If you have a transparent label that renders text and you use CALayer shadow properties, you'll get a text shadow out of them.